# Recognition of Geometric shapes for ridges

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning

I want to recognize these geometric shapes which are related to each other. For instance, looking at the image of the roof below, just by knowing the existence of the ridges in RED, I know that the ridge in BLUE should also exist (even if it is not visible in the image). If I have thousands of such labelled images, a ML model should be able to learn this as well. However, I can't figure out how to represent this problem?

[image: Original Image (Example 1)]

[image: Label over original Image (Example 1)]

**Label(s) : C, Z**

[image: Original Image (Example 2)]

[image: Label over original Image (Example 2)]

**Label(s) : D**

[image: Original Image (Example 3)]

[image: Label over original Image (Example 3)]

**Label(s) : C, Z**

[image: Original Image (Example 4)]

[image: Label over original Image (Example 4)]

**Label(s) : E, G**

Let's call these ridges as lines, as in the 1st example, we have X and Y lines being detected by simple edge detection but not Z because it's not visible. The same way line D is not detected but lines A, B, C are, from example 2.

What I want is that I formulate a ML model that learns from the X and Y that there should be a Z and subsequently D from A, B, C.

I have a data set of such examples where ridges are labeled (the red and blue is just to distinguish, all ridges are labeled with same color).

There are some important things to keep in mind.

- The brightness of the image could vary a lot.
- The ridge could have any scale or even orientation (within reasonable limits).
- The input image is almost always very noisy.

Comment: What are the ridges used for subsequently?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg we are using the ridges to create a structure of the roof. As in to divide it into sections

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches.

1. Use a network similar to those used in edge detection problems. These networks output probability for each pixel of Input to contain an edge. Your problem is similar, just that you don't need all the edges. But this may need some significant post processing as you may get a lot of close lying lines, you will have to collapse them into a single line using non maximal suppression or some morphological operation. For training the ground truth values can be binary masks containing true location of ridges or you can use some small gaussian over the actual ridge location so as to make loss function more stable.
2. Second method can be regression. You can have an output vector containing coordinates of end point of ridge as a flat vector. But that would require for you to fix maximum number of ridges that can be there. This method would not probably work on its own as you may get a lot of false positives due to bigger output vector, but this can be combined with first method and you can choose to keep a key point only if it's significantly close to an edge location obtained from first method.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CNN to do the detection of the roof. If color is not important, you can either make the image grayscale / other color channel models (e.g. HSV and remove the H-channel). Alternatively, you can augment your dataset by automatically changing the hue of any image and feeding this edited image to the CNN as well.